# Effect of $LANG on terminal

Tags: terminal, character-encoding, gnome-terminal, locale, terminal-emulator

I'm trying to **learn** how the `$LANG` variable behaves with gnome-terminal (and its character encoding preference option).  I've been using iso8859-1 (latin1) as my main character-set and all my filenames are encoded as such.

For the following tests I'll do an `ls -l` of a directory with Spanish accented characters in their filenames:

**Case #1:**

- gnome-terminal configured for ISO-8859-1
- `LANG` set to "en_US-iso8859-1"
- Result: I see all files correctly

**Case #2:**

- gnome-terminal configured for UTF-8
- `LANG` set to "en_US-iso8859-1"
- Result: I see garbage characters for all spanish characters. This is expected as I changed the character-encoding for the terminal

**Case #3:**

- gnome-terminal configured for ISO-8859-1
- `LANG` set to "en_US-UTF-8"
- Result: I see garbage characters for all spanish characters.

Why is that in this last case I see garbled characters? Shouldn't the output of **ls** send the filenames straight to gnome-terminal as they are? And since gnome-terminal is configured for ISO-8859-1, I would have expected them to look right.

For a moment I thought that, perhaps, maybe bash is considering my `$LANG` variable and performing some conversion. Then I switched my terminal to UTF-8 but I still can't see the characters right.  I even piped the output of ls to xxd and to my surprise I still see the files encoded as they are: ISO-8859-1.

To wrap up: If my listing contains ISO-8859-1 characters and my terminal emulator is configured for the same character-encoding: Who's doing the conversion when `LANG` is set otherwise?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Craconia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your setting for `LANG` must match the terminal's. More precisely, your setting for `LC_CTYPE` (the character encoding) must match the terminal's encoding, the other locale settings don't need to match. And the terminal's encoding is usually specified by an option of the terminal emulator and not by a locale variable. The `LC_CTYPE` combines two indications: it tells applications what encoding to use on the terminal (both for input and output), and it tells applications what encoding to use with files. In cases 2 and 3, you've told `ls` to display output in an encoding that's different from the terminal's, so the output is garbled.

If you work with both UTF-8 and latin-1 encodings at different times, configure your terminal to use UTF-8. This should cause it to set `LC_CTYPE` to a value indicating UTF-8; don't override this setting. (If the terminal emulator doesn't set `LC_CTYPE`, do override it in your shell startup file or for your whole session.) To work with latin-1 data in an UTF-8 terminal, use [`luit`](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/luit/) (included in the X utility suite).

```
LC_CTYPE=en_US.iso88591 luit
```

(You can use any other locale with the same encoding, e.g. `LC_CTYPE=es_ES.iso88591 luit`.)

Comment: Thanks Gilles for that wonderful explanation, especially for explaining the two indications for LC_CTYPE.

Comment: Going back to my last case:  I thought that, since all filenames were encoded in latin1 plus the fact that my final output device, the one creating the glyphs (my terminal) was also configured for latin1, I was expecting to see the files correctly (regardless of LC_CTYPE)...

Comment: It never occurred to me that `ls` would consider LC_CTYPE (set to UTF-8 in this case) and would perform some kind of character-set validation: whenever it sees something not compatible with the character set it would spit a specific character (e.g."?").  I said "validation" because it won't perform a "conversion" as luit does.

Is it like this?

Comment: @Craconia In the third case, `ls` replaces the unprintable characters by `?`. Most strings encoded in latin-1 that represent real words are have unprintable characters if interpreted as UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

In case #2 and #3 you're mixing two different encoding UTF-8 and Latin-1.
In case #1 you're using Latin-1 for both, so you don't have a problem.

The `ls` command (and all other well behaving programms) use the LANG setting for determining the **encoding**.

You may mixing two different Languages, but you **shouldn't mix two different encodings**.

Ensure that the LC_* environment variables are also use the the same encoding as your LANG variable.

As a rule of thumb you should configure your system nowadays to use only UTF-8.

If you have to edit old fashioned data files (e.g. java properties) you should either use a specialized editor (e.g. java ide) or ensure the encoding with tools like `iconv` or `recode..

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have plans to switch to UTF-8 in the near future. Got a bunch of filenames to convert plus many many text files.  iconv & convmv to the rescue...

Answer (score 0):

This might be outside of your need, but ....

It turns out in RHEL5, and probably prior, many of the man pages have somehow for some gd foresaken reason, been ascii-ized. That is, the raw man page has been converted from its native character set to 7-bit ASCII. No matter what you do with LC and LANG, the man page for `latin1` produces a man page which is effectively useless. All special (8-bit) characters within have been replaced with 7-bit placeholders (usually `??`). I find this hilarious.

But the `utf8` version of these man pages might exist in the language-specific directory. The trick is to ask for them by their right name. For instance, latin1 is actually `iso_8859-1`. If you do a man page on it, and your LANG settings are correct, you see what you expect; the man page is found in the language-specific subdir (`en/man7/iso_8859-1.7`). But if you ask for `iso-8859-1`, for some reason, you get the ASCII version.